# If continuous images of $X$ are closed in every $Y$, is $X$ a compact space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $X$ is a topological space. We have the following criterion for compactness:

**Theorem.** $X$ is compact if and only if for every space $Y$, the second projection $\pi_2: X\times Y \to Y$ is a closed map.

This property is known as being *universally closed*, and also plays an important role in algebraic geometry (in the definition of a *proper morphism*). The proof of the result above can be found on [this MSE thread.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1687984/49227)

My question is whether we can strengthen this result by only asking that the graphs of continuous functions have closed image in $Y$. From now on, we will consider only Hausdorff topological spaces.

**Question.** Is it true that a Hausdorff space $X$ is compact if and only if for every continuous map $f: X\to Y$ with $Y$ Hausdorff has a closed image $f(X)$ in $Y$.

More context for the question: let $X$ and $Y$ be any two Hausdorff spaces. For any continuous function $f: X\to Y$ we can consider its graph $\Gamma(f) = \{(x, y)\in X\times Y: y=f(x)\}$. Note that $\Gamma(f)\subset X\times Y$ is a closed subset of $Y$ (see [this MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108709/is-the-graph-g-f-x-fx-in-x-times-y-x-in-x-a-closed-subset-of-x) for proof). If $X$ were compact, then we know that the image of $\Gamma(f)$ under the second projection map $X\times Y\to Y$ would be closed. Note that the image of $\Gamma(f)$ is precisely the image $f(X)=\{f(x)\in Y: x\in X\}$, and so $f(X)$ would be closed in $Y$. This shows that the forward implication is true (one can show this implication in a more direct away). It makes sense to ask whether the converse also holds.

Comment: This is related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-closed_space

Comment: Moreover, if your space is $T_{3.5}$, you can embed it in a compactification; since its image is by assumption closed, it means your space really is compact. I imagine there is a counterexample for non T3.5 spaces.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Stone–Čech compactification mentions the existence of a Hausdorff space on which any continuous real-valued function is constant, although it does not demonstrate such one and only cites a book as a reference.

Comment: @SangchulLee There are descriptions of such a space on MSE if you look for them..

Comment: @Henno Could you provide a reference for one of those MSE threads? I couldn't locate them myself. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @SangchulLee [this therad](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1046079/4280) has some references and descriptions. So we can take  $Y=\Bbb R$ and we get and $X$ (regular $T_1$) that only has constant maps into $\Bbb R$. Nothing special about the reals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Hausdorff space $X$ is *H-closed* if, for every Hausdorff space $Y$ and a topological embedding $f:X\to Y$, the image $f(X)$ is closed.

**Lemma**. A Hausdorff space $X$ is H-closed if and only if for every Hausdorff space $Y$ and a continuous map $f:X\to Y$, the image $f(X)$ is closed.

**Lemma**. The topological space $[0,1]$, with the smallest topology containing the both the standard one and the set $\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, is H-closed.

The latter space is not compact, since it contains $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ (with the standard topology) as a closed subset, while $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ is not compact (with the standard topology).

Comment: Why does H-closed imply that every continuous function to a Hausdorff space has closed image?

Comment: there's a proof here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/237974. In fact it is more or less the same question...

Comment: Ok. That is neat.

Comment: Yeah, it is! Although perhaps I should have added that this is impossible for T3.5 spaces... Not sure about T3, though.